# Installing GSL libraries in Ubuntu 16.04 via terminal

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am having trouble installing the GSL libraries through terminal, I found some command line options such as

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl
```

but this did not work and I got errors that there are no installation packages found.

How do I go about fixing this and installing `gsl` through using the command line?

Comment: Do you really need the GSL *libraries*? or the  [GSL development package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgsl-dev)?

Answer (score 43):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
```

It should work on Ubuntu 18.04 as well.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 and allowed me to install the R package [Rfast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfast/index.html).

Comment: Still work on Ubuntu 22.04 (necessary for package MVN)

Answer (score 7):

There is no quick terminal method to install gsl.  The best tutorial for installation I've found is here:

https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/

Once you have done all the steps in the tutorial it would be nice to not have to type `-L/home/...` and `-I/home/user/...`.  There are a few ways to do this, one way is to make an alias for gcc but I wouldn't recommend it.

I think the best way is to move the include files and the lib files to their appropriate directories.  To move the include files type:

```
sudo cp -r /home/yourname/gsl/include/gsl/ /usr/include/
```

where "yourname" is the name you used for the install (the one in the tutorial).

To move the library files I used:

```
sudo cp /home/yourname/gsl/lib/libgsl* /usr/lib/
sudo cp /home/yourname/gsl/lib/pkgconfig/gsl.pc /usr/lib/pkgconfig/
```

This should work on most ubuntu installations (at least it worked on my 16.04 64 bit installation) and you should be able to compile without the use of the I and L flags.

**Update** : Ever since ubuntu 18.04, more modern versions of GSL are installed using the default command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
```

Once you do this you can run your program with:

```
g++ -std=c++1X <your_program>.cpp -o <output_name> -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Type `sudo apt install libgsl` and press tab twice. This should print out all available packages starting with 'libgsl'. Then end the command with the one ending with a number which is in my case `libgsl23`, but if you use an older version of Ubuntu than 18.04 then you might have it end with a smaller number.